# px.line_mapbox how can I connect the points correctly?

Tags: plotly

I try to plot road segment data with lat and lon. The data represents parts of roads as a path to a destination. How can I connect the points so that the lines represent the road correctly?

With px.scatter_mapbox it looks like expcected:

[image]

This is what it looks like with px.line_mapbox and what I want to correct:

[image]

The data looks like this:

```
lat,lon
49.9138598,8.6546538
49.9056928,8.6609511
49.9137963,8.6547367
49.9031554,8.6602001
49.9036356,8.6605441
49.9101238,8.6713172
49.9031909,8.6578803
49.9031801,8.6584378
49.908962,8.657051
49.9031524,8.6603878
49.908962,8.657029
49.9089642,8.6571283
49.9089628,8.6570803
49.9089621,8.656988
49.9031758,8.6585998
49.9031293,8.6629121
49.9031306,8.6628223
49.9089685,8.657193
49.9061892,8.6563651
49.9061913,8.6564502
49.9089642,8.6571283
49.9090377,8.6580812
49.904322,8.6607755
49.9089749,8.6572878
49.9122419,8.666437
49.9090437,8.6589592
49.909642,8.6555025
49.9031476,8.6612382
49.9033839,8.6557096
49.9033763,8.6557774
49.9113246,8.6590449
```

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(road, lat="lat", lon="lon",
                        hover_data={'lat':False, 'lon':False}, zoom=11, height=500)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Comment: The first example is from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-mapbox/#lines-on-mapbox-maps-using-plotly-express), since the data used is a list of latitudes and longitudes, and the second is a line segment in geometry form. The second is a line segment in geometry format, otherwise it will not be a continuous line.

Answer (score 1):

- a few concepts.  Lines are a sequence of points, hence the order is critical
- using https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp#circuit_board approach you can find a sequence
- have used this to generate `tsp` list (code not in this answer)
- this then leads to a meaning full sequence

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import io

road = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""lat,lon
49.9138598,8.6546538
49.9056928,8.6609511
49.9137963,8.6547367
49.9031554,8.6602001
49.9036356,8.6605441
49.9101238,8.6713172
49.9031909,8.6578803
49.9031801,8.6584378
49.908962,8.657051
49.9031524,8.6603878
49.908962,8.657029
49.9089642,8.6571283
49.9089628,8.6570803
49.9089621,8.656988
49.9031758,8.6585998
49.9031293,8.6629121
49.9031306,8.6628223
49.9089685,8.657193
49.9061892,8.6563651
49.9061913,8.6564502
49.9089642,8.6571283
49.9090377,8.6580812
49.904322,8.6607755
49.9089749,8.6572878
49.9122419,8.666437
49.9090437,8.6589592
49.909642,8.6555025
49.9031476,8.6612382
49.9033839,8.6557096
49.9033763,8.6557774
49.9113246,8.6590449"""))

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(road, lat="lat", lon="lon",
                        hover_name=road.index,
                        hover_data={'lat':False, 'lon':False}, zoom=11, height=500)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

tsp = [0, 2, 30, 25, 21, 23, 17, 20, 11, 12, 8, 10, 13, 26, 18, 19, 28, 29, 6, 7, 14, 3, 9, 27, 16, 15, 4, 22, 1, 5, 24]

fig.add_traces(px.line_mapbox(road.loc[tsp], lat="lat", lon="lon").data)
```

[image]